# How to make picturebox transparent when it comes above another image at runtime

Tags: c#, runtime, picturebox, transparent

I am making an application in C#.net. I have a picture in my background form.I have several picture boxes on it.I used .png images with transparent background but in my form it is not transparent when it comes above another image. I am using visual studio 2012. This is the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: You cant do this with picture box because if you set picturebox's back ground color as transparent then it will take it's parent background and that is your form in this case not any other pictureboxes.

Comment: Transparency is simulated, it draws the Parent first to provide the background, then draws the Image.  Which works well until you start to overlap controls, you only see the Parent and not the controls you overlap.  Do keep in mind that PictureBox is just a point-and-click convenience, it is a poor substitute for the single line of code you need in the form's Paint event handler to accomplish the same thing.  Graphics.DrawImage() gets the job done too.  Faster too.  Now layering works fine.